# will tcp socket recv return "resource temporarily unavailable" when recv buf already have data

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, tcp, recv

I implement TCP socket communication using epoll to monitor all the client events, only one thread process all the client in a for loop. every socket is non-blocking.

now I just suffered a problem,  when client send data more than MTU, means several fragment packet, server always can't read all the data completely.
like below, I read the head first, get the pdu len from the head, then read the pdu part.

the problem is though I read the head successfully, closely following with the pdu recv(), but it always return EAGAIN several times. so my retry will break.
Because server needs to process thousands of client event, so I think it is a great performance consumptionn to let the retry always continue which is not tolerable.

I use tcpdump capturing the packets from client, every packet is fragment to max 1448 bytes data, but head is only 5 bytes, why I can read the head successfully, but the following data recv() operation will return EAGAIN? is it possible recv return EAGAIN when data already arrive the recv buffer?  In my opinion, I can read the first 5 bytes, so must have more data to read in the recv buffer.

maybe related with the assemble process in tcp/ip stack.
code is like below, every pdu recv, need 10 or more retry, maybe success.

```
...
#define HDR_LEN    5
n = epoll(epfd, events, 1000, -1)
for(i =0; i < n; i++)
{
    uint8 pHdr[HDR_LEN] = {0};
    uint16 pdulen = 0, offset =0;
    infd = events[i].fd;
    nRead = recv(infd, pHdr, HDR_LEN);   // read the data head first
    pdulen = ntohs(*(uint16 *)(pHdr+2));   // get the pdu len from the head
    uint8 *pbuf = malloc(pdulen+HDR_LEN);

    memcpy(pbuf, pHdr, HDR_LEN);            // move the head to buf
    while(offset != pdulen)                 // then read the pdu data
    {
        nRead = recv(infd, pbuf+HDR_LEN+offset, pdulen-offset);
        if (nRead <=0)
        {
            if (nRead == -1 && errno == EAGAIN) // resource temporarily unavailable 
            {
                if (retry < 5)
                {
                    usleep(500);
                    retry++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                     break;  // already try 5 times, should always continue?
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        else
        {
             offset += nRead;
             retry = 0;
        }
    }
    if (offset == pdulen)
        process(pbuf, pdulen+HDR_LEN); // process the complete data
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: please some help, help out of this problem!

Comment: Is your socket in non-blocking mode? If so, then EAGAIN is to be expected whenever there is no more data left in the receive buffer to retrieve. In order to handle non-blocking I/O of multiple sockets simultaneously, you'll need to implement a state machine so that you can go back your normal poll() call after having received a partial response.  Then when poll() indicates there is more data to read on your socket, then (and only then) should you go back and recv() the additional data from the socket, appending it to the data you got from that socket previously, until you've got the whole PDU.

Comment: 'Will tcp socket recv return “resource temporarily unavailable” when recv buf already have data?' No.

Answer (score 2):

`epoll` will tell you if you can `recv` without blocking, once. If `recv` consumes all data from the socket, then next `recv` will block until there's more data, or return EAGAIN (if non-blocking socket).

A common pattern is to:

1. Use `select/poll/epoll` to detect when a socket can be read.
2. Call `recv` once on a ready socket and append received data to a buffer.
3. Check if the buffer contains enough data for processing. If yes, then process. Otherwise let `select/poll/epoll` tell when you can read more.